# Is it possible to resize gallery thumbnails?

Tags: gallery

I want to reduce the thumbnail size of the videos in Gallery.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You mean how large the preview image appears within the Gallery app?  Or how large the cached thumbnail image is?  Or something else?

Comment: I meant the size of the preview pictures. More specifically, I want to see more thumbnails per screen regardless how this is achieved. For example, it shows 10 thumbnails per screen on my tablet. I would like to see at least 20  per screen.